# Java add object to ArrayList<object>

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

Here is my class :

```
class phoneNumber{
    private String number;
    private boolean valid;

    public void phoneNumber(String n, boolean v){
        number = n;
        valid = v;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }

    public void appendNumber(String number) {
        this.number = this.number + number;
    }

    public boolean getValidity(){
        return this.valid;
    }

    public void setValidity(boolean validity){
        this.valid = validity;
    }
}
```

Here is the declaration of the ArrayList :

```
private static ArrayList<phoneNumber> outputN = new ArrayList<phoneNumber>();
```

But I can't add an object to this list. when I try to add a new one like this:

```
outputN.add(new phoneNumber("0000000000", false));
```

I get this error :

> phoneNumber( )  in phoneNumber cannot be applied to (java.lang.String,
>   boolean)

Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constructors don't have return types

```
public phoneNumber(String n, boolean v) {
```

Comment: Some would argue that constructors have no names, only the return type, which must match the name of the class, but that's all the same :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your class constructor should be written like this:

```
public phoneNumber(String n, boolean v)
```

Class constructors do not need a `return` type.

Answer (score 0):

Use constructor

```
public phoneNumber(String n, boolean v) {
    number = n;
    valid = v;
}
```

And add as flowing

```
outputN.add(new phoneNumber("0000000000", false));
```

Comment: Also ad public String toString() {..} to write as [phoneNumber{number='0000000000', valid=false}]